# Determine if Host Is Resolved DNS Name Or IP

Tags: c#, .net, dns, ip, httprequest

If one is extracting a `HOST` value from an `HttpContext`'s `HttpRequest`'s `Headers`  collection, is there a way of determining if the value returned is a DNS resolved name or a direct IP address?

**Example Usage**

```
 string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["HOST"]; 

 if (host.IsIPAddress()) ... /// Something like this ?
     or
    (host.IsDNSResolved()) // Or this?
```

**Summary**

It is obvious that one could do a regex pattern test on the result to look for an IP pattern, but is there a property on `HttpContext` or more likely `HttpRequest`, or even an external static method off of a helper class which could do that determination instead?

Comment: Maybe an ancillary question might be, how in .Net can one get a DNS list? Albeit huge...

Comment: The Host header is sent by the client (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). From the server side, you could use Request.UserHostName and/or Request.UserHostAddress instead of using client headers?

Comment: I did not understand the purpose of reading HOST value as it will be same as where your server is deployed unless it is sitting behind a Load Balancer on a different server as the server handling the request.

One way you can do is use Dns.GetHostName() to get the HostName of the machine where this statement gets executed to compare against the value you've read from HOST header

Comment: @Gururaj The code was originally behind something, *I can't remember it was a year and a half ago*, but yes it needed to know something about a resolved name vs an IP to properly route.

Comment: @OmegaMan - You can use Dns.GetHostName() to get hold of HostName and compare it against Host value from the header. I hope it should resolve your concern

Comment: @Gururaj add an example answer so I can mark as the answer if no others come up.

Comment: @OmegaMan - I've added an example answer using above comment. Please accept it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Gururaj Patience. :-) I will award when the 5 day bounty is up. In case there is another answer. Upvote the question if you haven't already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about [`Uri.CheckHostName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.checkhostname(v=vs.110).aspx)?

This returns a [`System.UriHostNameType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urihostnametype(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example:

```
Uri.CheckHostName("127.0.0.1"); //=> IPv4
Uri.CheckHostName("www.google.com"); //=> Dns
Uri.CheckHostName("localhost"); //=> Dns
Uri.CheckHostName("2000:2000:2000:2000::"); //=> IPv6
```

Of course, to use the way you suggested, the easiest way is to create an extension, like so:

```
    public static class UriExtension {
        public static bool IsIPAddress(this string input) {
            var hostNameType = Uri.CheckHostName(input);

            return hostNameType == UriHostNameType.IPv4 || hostNameType == UriHostNameType.IPv6;
        }
    }
```

And this is the result:

```
"127.0.0.1".IsIPAddress(); //true
"2000:2000:2000:2000::".IsIPAddress(); //true
"www.google.com".IsIPAddress(); //false
```

Comment: Just FYI for everyone - Uri.CheckHostName("10"); //=> IPv4. So, its not reliable.

Answer (score 7):

You can take advantage of the [`System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse Method (String, IPAddress)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) and create an extension method to perform the desired functionality.

```
public static class IpAddressExtension {
    public static bool IsIPAddress(this string ipAddress) {
        System.Net.IPAddress address = null;
        return System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out address);
    }
}
```

This now allows the following

```
string host = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["HOST"];

if (host.IsIPAddress()) {
    //...valid ip address
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is use Dns.GetHostName() to get the HostName of the machine where this statement gets executed to compare against the value you've read from HOST header - something like this

```
var host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["HOST"];
var machineHostName = Dns.GetHostName();

if(host.ToLower().Equals(machineHostName.ToLower()))
{
    // Perform your action here.
}
```